# How to say "Take public transport instead of driving" in the imperatif?

Tags: grammaire, impératif

Is it "Prenez les transports en commun au lieu de **conduire, conduisez, or something else**?" and why? Also, what would the sentence be if "driving" was swapped with "moving in a car" (using se deplacer instead of conduire)? Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

As for your first question,after **au lieu de** we use the infinitive so conduire is correct.

As for your second question,the sentence would be "Prenez les transports en commun au lieu de vous deplacer en voiture"."Se deplacer" is a reflexive verb and we change *se* into *vous* since the subject of the sentence is vous.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense! Why is it vous deplacer instead of vous deplacez or se deplacer?

Comment: As I said after au lieu de we use an infinitive not the indicative.We say vous deplacer and not se deplacer since prenez refers to vous.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly rephrasing the sentence to get something lighter:

> Utilisez les transports en commun plutôt que votre voiture !